# MySQL group by with multiple column sums and a total sum for each group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
Votes (id, person, positive_vote, negative_vote)
```

I want to group by person and and sort by total votes for each person. I know how to get the total sum of a single column for a group, but I can't figure out how to get the total of all the sum for each group (the total votes).

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT person, sum(positive_vote), sum(negative_vote) FROM Votes GROUP BY person;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try,

```
SELECT person, 
       sum(positive_vote) totalPositive, 
       sum(negative_vote) totalNegative,
       (sum(positive_vote) + sum(negative_vote)) totalVotes
FROM Votes 
GROUP BY person
-- HAVING (sum(positive_vote) + sum(negative_vote)) < 5
```

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to add a `WHERE` on totalVotes? I'm getting an error. I added it on the end like this `GROUP BY person WHERE totalVotes < 5;'

Comment: @ScottBartell use `having` instead of `where`, `HAVING (sum(positive_vote) + sum(negative_vote)) < 5`

Comment: FYI: I had to use `( IFNULL(SUM(col1), 0) + IFNULL(SUM(col2), 0) )`. Otherwise the calculation failed and the result was `(NULL)`. [MySQL IFNULL()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Answer (score 4):

If you want the total for each person, just subtract the sums (or add them instead if you just want a total *number* of votes):

```
SELECT person, sum(positive_vote), sum(negative_vote),
    SUM(positive_vote)-SUM(negative_vote)
FROM Votes 
GROUP BY person
```

Note I have subtracted *the sums* here and not summed the difference of the columns themselves because I do not know how you are storing data in your table and NULLs can do funny things with math.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Z.person,Z.sum_pv,Z.sum_nv,Z.diff_sum_pv_nv
FROM
(SELECT person, sum(positive_vote) AS sum_pv, sum(negative_vote) sum_nv,sum(positive_vote) - sum(negative_vote) AS diff_sum_pv_nv
FROM Votes GROUP BY person)Z;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the sum of positive_vote and negative_vote?

```
SELECT 
  person, 
  SUM(positive_vote) AS positive_votes, 
  SUM(negative_vote) AS negative_votes,
  SUM(positive_vote + negative_vote) AS total_votes
FROM Votes GROUP BY person;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT person, 
       sum(positive_vote) as totalPositive, 
       sum(negative_vote) as totalNegative,
       (sum(positive_vote + negative_vote)) as totalVotes
FROM Votes 
GROUP BY person
```